# is there a way to do a meteor find() based upon more than one field?

Tags: meteor, find

Is there a way to do a meteor find (yes, it will be part of a publish function later, i'm just trying to test this)
that is filtered by more than one field at a time?
for example, let's say I only want to return those users who work at Disney in the IT department.

so far I have

```
Template.managerReports.disney = function () {  
return employees.find({'company':"disney"});         
};

//for template helper binding to
<template name="managerReports">
{{#each disney}}
 <p>{{name}}</p>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

and attempts to add multiple comma-separated {field:value} pairs results very nicely in these ALSO being found and added to the disney results. I want to reduce results per added field. only data that matches multiple fields gets found.

am I being totally dumb? what is the usual meteor way to deal with multiple conditional finds?

Comment: what do i do? you BOTH gave "correct answers" ? how does it work around here? i'm going with the first one as it was 1) first and 2) added extra info, although the second answer was awesome too, in that it told me specifically what format i needed to pass. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find users who work for disney **AND** in the IT department:

```js
employees.find($and: [{company: 'disney'}, {department: 'it'}]);
```

However, mongodb provides an implicit **AND** operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions. So this is more commonly written as:

```js
employees.find({company: 'disney', department: 'it'});
```

If you want to find users who work for disney **OR** in the IT department:

```js
employees.find($or: [{company: 'disney'}, {department: 'it'}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a javascript object, not comma-separated values:

```
Employees.find({
  company: 'disney',
  department: 'marketing',
  salary: {$gt: 100000},
});
```